# Python 3 Tkinter: How can you mix two sides in a Frame eg. button(side="bottom-left")

Tags: python, tkinter

I am *still* making my Text Editor in Python and now I'm stuck with putting two buttons in a frame and making them both in the bottom part. So here's my code:

```
def frame1():
frame1 = Tk()
def close():
    frame1.destroy()
frame1.title("Colour")
frame1.geometry("340x196")
label = ttk.Label(frame1, text="Font Colour", font=DefaultFont)
label.pack(side="top")
Button1 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Okay", command=close)
Button1.pack(side="bottom", fill=X)
Button2 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Discard", command=close)
Button2.pack(side="bottom", fill=X)
frame1.mainloop()
```

And here's what I got:
[.*gY graphical output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TIsi.png)

Basically, I need both buttons to be in the bottom part of my frame and also I'd like to use the "fill=X" thing.

Comment: You should look into the `grid` function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a frame for the buttons. Pack the frame on the bottom, and the buttons left-to-right inside the frame.

Example:

```
buttonframe = Frame(frame1)
buttonframe.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

Button1 = ttk.Button(buttonframe, ...)
Button2 = ttk.Button(buttonframe, ...)
Button1.pack(side="left")
Button2.pack(side="right")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) It helped me a lot.